# If a function uses a static heap-allocated-variable, is there any point in using a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, static, smart-pointers

If a function, e.g. like this random-number engine, uses a static variable, is there any point in using a smart pointer? Since the objects is initialised when the function is first called and stays alive until the program ends, both versions have the same effect? Is no chance that this could leak memory?

edit: I added `thread_local` since I actually use it to get may random numbers in parallel.

```
std::mt19937_64& generator()
{
  if(!mt)
    static thread_local std::mt19937_64* mt = new std::mt19937_64(std::random_device{}());
  return *mt;
}

//compared to:

std::mt19937_64& generator()
{
  if(!mt)
    static thread_local std::unique_ptr<std::mt19937_64> mt = make_unique<std::mt19937_64>(std::random_device{}());
  return *mt;
}
```

Comment: Why allocate dynamically at all? If the requirement is to not store it on the stack then local `static` variables aren't (can't be really) stored on the stack anyway. Also, not all operating systems might have resource tracking and don't free resources when the process ends, so a memory leak in a program will lead to a permanent leak.

Comment: This seems like an odd implementation. Why not just have a normal `static` variable? There's no need for the dynamic allocation.

Comment: But if it's not dynamically allocated, how can I ensure the engine will not be overwritten on the next call? Currently it's ensured with the `if(!mt)` condition.

Comment: @dani function-scope statics are only initialized on the first call.

Comment: @dani compiler takes care of this, it will initialize mt on the first use, also for c++ `magic statics` takes care of thread safe initialization of static objects.

Comment: Your code as written don't actually work, you use `mt` in your condition before it has been declared, and then you declare it in the nested scope of the `if` statement so it's not possible to use the variable in the `return` since it's no longer in scope. The `if` check is not needed at all for `static` variables.

Comment: " also for c++ " should be  also for "c++11  and up"

Comment: You should Compile with higher warning Level and you might see warnings for what Joachim Pileborg mentioned.